# why does it stop half way through my code?

Tags: java, tags

So the first part creates a vector and adds a digit to the 10 slots. Then after this nothing happens, i have no errors in my code but it just stops.. why?

```
package ovn7;    
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ovn7a {

    int []vektor;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static void main(String []args) {

        int []vektor = new int[10];

        for(int k=1; k<10; k++){
            vektor[k]=0+k;
            System.out.println(k);
        }
    }
    public int find(int tal) {

        System.out.println("tal");
        tal = scan.nextInt();
        int i = 0;
        while(i<10 && vektor[i] != tal) {
            i++;    
        }
        return (i <10) ? i : -1;
    }

}
```

Comment: What more do you expect to happen? It looks like your `main` function has completed. Your other function is declared but never called.

Comment: I dont know whats gonna happen. I copy code from my book to see whats gonna happen since it doesnt explain well enough in the book. If I change the 'public static void main(String []args)' } sign to the bottom I get mass errors. After a few fixes I have to change that line to public  int main(String []args) {. I have no idea why. I still get a error which I cannot fix on the `public int find(int tal) {` part. The error reads Multiple markers at this line
  Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
  Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
  Illegal modifier for parameter find; only final is 
  permi

Comment: I strongly advise against programming through blind experimentation. It's a foolproof way to confuse yourself even more! I suggest you grab a guide online or use the book you currently have to learn about how methods work in Java. With that knowledge, you'll be well-equipped to improve your program!

Answer (score 0):

This is your main method:

```
public static void main(String []args) {
    int []vektor = new int[10];
    for(int k=1; k<10; k++){
        vektor[k]=0+k;
        System.out.println(k);
    }
}
```

That's all your program does - when it hits the closing right brace of the main method, execution ends. If you want it to execute `public int find(int tal)` as well, you need to include a method call to your main method:

```
int index = find(5); //for example
```

Remember, the `main` method is the only one that is called automatically when executing the program! You'll have to call `find` yourself inside `main`.

EDIT: per request, an example of main with the method call included:

```
public static void main(String []args) {
    int []vektor = new int[10];
    for(int k=1; k<10; k++){
        vektor[k]=0+k;
        System.out.println(k);
    }
    int index = find(5); // <-- this find(5) here is a method call for find!
    System.out.println("The method returned a value of " + index + ".");
}
```

You can replace that "5" with any integer, as the method `find` accepts an integer as an argument. (as a side note, it doesn't matter which integer you pass to find - it overwrites the argument with a new value anyway)

Comment: How do I "call find"? I tried to add main to my int line so it became `public int main find(int tal) {` but that didnt work

Comment: I'll add an example to my answer shortly. However, it seems that you don't really understand methods yet so I also advice you to read more on them.

Comment: I dont.. and ive tried to read on them and i dont get them. I understand the normal code or what you call it but i dont get anything about methods almost.. sigh

Comment: That's too bad, then - I can't really answer your question any further if you don't understand how methods work, because this is all about them.